# Difference between union type LUB and supertype LUB

Tags: scala, scala-3, subtyping, dotty

List of shapes infers to `List[Shape]` but list of boxed shapes infers to `List[Box[Square | Circle]]`

```
scala> sealed trait Shape
     | case class Square() extends Shape
     | case class Circle() extends Shape
     | case class Box[+T <: Shape](t: T)
     | List(Square(), Circle())
     | List(Box(Square()), Box(Circle()))
val res0: List[Shape & Product & Serializable] = List(Square(), Circle())
val res1: List[Box[Square | Circle]] = List(Box(Square()), Box(Circle()))
```

Why is `res0` not typed to `List[Square | Circle]` in symmetry with `List[Box[Square | Circle]]`, or vice-versa?

Dotty defines [least upper bound](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types-spec.html#subtyping-rules) in terms of union types

> the least upper bound (lub) of a set of types is the union of these
>   types. This replaces the [definition of least upper bound in the Scala
>   2 specification.](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#least-upper-bounds-and-greatest-lower-bounds)

What are the rules now for unification relative to this change?

Comment: It would certainly make more sense to infer `res1` to `List[Box[Shape]]` in this case, where they both extend a trait and you might want to add `Box[Rectangle]`, etc. later on

Comment: Not sure if this is the only problem, but `Box[Square] | Box[Circle]` is not a thing because of type erasure

Comment: @simpadjo Type erasure is irrelevant because type erasure occurs long after typechecking https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/internals/overall-structure.html `Box[Square] with Box[Circle]` exists even in Scala 2.

Comment: @DmytroMitin but how is pattern-matching on `Box[Square] | Box[Circle]` possible at runtime?

Comment: @simpadjo You can [check](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/257729dddd733527d4445903cd16047c) this with `scalacOptions += "-Xprint:genBCode"`. Basically it's matched with `Box[_]` at runtime. But once again this is irrelevant to type inference/typechecking.

Comment: @MarioGalic Quote from http://guillaume.martres.me/talks/dotty-tutorial/#/1/13 (slide 15 "Type inference and union types"): "By default, Dotty does not infer union types, they are approximated by a non-union supertype. Union types can be "too precise" and prevent legitimate code from compiling"

Comment: @MarioGalic although maybe this is outdated