# How does Dotty decide how to infer/when to widen Union Types?

Tags: scala, type-inference, union-types, dotty, scala-3

Widening Union Types have been discussed [here](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/union-type-widening/1069) but I can't seem to find an answer to the following case

Let's start by looking at the following

```
val x = List(1, 2, "a")
```

This heterogeneous list is inferred as `List[Any]` Just like it would in Scala 2

However the following

```
val x2 = List(List(1, 2), Vector("a", "b"))
```

is inferred as `List[scala.collection.immutable.AbstractSeq[Int | String]]`

This is rather confusing behavior. Why does two disjoint types' LUB get inferred as `Any` in one case but a union type in another?

If it is just a design decision, are there any such cases that one should be aware of ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[smarter](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/4867#issuecomment-409211465) states

> we avoid inferring union types for the same reason we avoid inferring
> singleton types, because sometimes they're "too precise"

My interpretation of this statement is that it makes more sense to type `List(1,2)` as `List[Int]` instead of `List[1 | 2]`, or `List(new Cat, new Dog)` as `List[Animal]` instead of `List[Cat | Dog]`.

See also Dmytro's comment from related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62120884/difference-between-union-type-lub-and-supertype-lub#comment110007272_62120884) (of mine)

> Quote from [guillaume.martres.me/talks/dotty-tutorial/#/1/13](http://guillaume.martres.me/talks/dotty-tutorial/#/1/13) (slide 15
> "Type inference and union types"): "By default, Dotty does not infer
> union types, they are approximated by a non-union supertype. Union
> types can be "too precise" and prevent legitimate code from compiling"

Also see mention at [23:38](https://youtu.be/YIQjfCKDR5A?t=1418) of the talk "Dotty and types: the story so far".

However widening of union is performed only **once** to avoid infinite LUB as per [smarter](https://gitter.im/lampepfl/dotty?at=5d2dbe9f7dbfff3242ba2dd0):

> when we do the widening once, the resulting type might have a union
> somewhere (like the example in the section [Join of a union type](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/c104e9b1b7c028f114f8f3c0331198a9587391b5/docs/docs/reference/new-types/union-types-spec.md#join-of-a-union-type) in
> the doc), we won't widen that if we did do the widening recursively,
> we could get an infinite lub indeed

Comment: I saw that comment and the video but it didn't quite answer my question to be honest. I think I have some what of an understanding of why they went with the decision of not inferring union types but I am still not clear on why, in your example, `List[Box[Square | Circle]]` inferred as a union? If inferring union types is hard, why wasn't it hard in this case? Did I miss something in the comments or the video?

Comment: @sinanspd It seems widening of union is performed only once to avoid infinite lub as per [smarter](https://gitter.im/lampepfl/dotty?at=5d2dbe9f7dbfff3242ba2dd0): _"if we did do the widening recursively, we could get an infinite lub indeed"_ Also see [Join of a union type](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types-spec.html#join-of-a-union-type)

Comment: Thanks Mario! I thought the infinite lub was prevented by intersection types but I guess there is more to that story. Can you Guillaume's comment in the answer so I can accept this? I think that is the most direct answer to this question